# Creating tests for AppModel.php

Tags: phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I am new to Unit testing and I am trying to create some tests for the functions within AppModel.php in CakePHP 2.0.

My AppModelTest.php looks like:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class AppModelTestCase extends CakeTestCase {
    public $fixtures = array();

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->AppModel = ClassRegistry::init('AppModel');
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->AppModel);
        ClassRegistry::flush();
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testMultibyteSlug() {
        $result = $this->AppModel->slug('abet!"£$%*$%^&yurgerfui94873');
        $this->assertEqual($result, 'abet-yurgerfui94873');
        .....
```

When I try to run the tests I get:

```
MissingTableException

Database table app_models for model AppModel was not found.
Test case: AppModelTestCase(testMultibyteSlug)
Stack trace:
C:\xampp\htdocs\wdmmg2\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php : 3258
C:\xampp\htdocs\wdmmg2\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php : 720
C:\xampp\htdocs\wdmmg2\app\Test\Case\Model\AppModelTest.php : 39
C:\xampp\htdocs\wdmmg2\app\Test\Case\Model\AppModelTest.php : 39
AppModelTestCase::testMultibyteSlug
```

Can anybody help me as I do not know where to start or what I am doing wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: Where is the database table? See the error message: `Database table app_models for model AppModel was not found.`

Comment: Sorry to waste time but I have found the problem. It was the line: $result = $this->AppModel->slug('abet!"£$%*$%^&yurgerfui94873'); as the function slug() has been replaced by multibyteSlug()